# java transient variable type must be known for serialization?

Tags: java, types, serializable, transient

I noticed that in Java, you can use a class which has members of types that are unavailable to you. For example, say you have a precompiled `.class` file for the following `Person` class; but not for `Address`, which it uses:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String sex;
    private String name;
    private transient Address address;

    public Person(String sex, String name) {
        this.sex = sex; this.name = name; 
    }
    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address
    }
}
```

You can instantiate this class with `Person person = Person("Male", "Andrew");` even if the type `Address` is not available to your Java project.

Now the problem is, if you want to serialize a `Person` object, you cannot do this unless the `Address` type is available (i.e. can be loaded by the class loader), even though the `Address` field **is transient**.

For some reason Java needs to know the type `Address` even though it will not need to serialize it...

Any help on how I could serialize `Person` anyway without having to redefine a `Person` class without an address? And any explanation of why Java needs to know the type of address although it will not need to serialize it?

Many thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to tell........ Do you mean Address being null?

Comment: No, Address being an undefined type, this means: having no class file of Address. Read matts' answer below if you want the answer to this question. He answered it correctly.

Comment: I have edited your question to match the assumption posed by the answer you accepted. If this is really what you were going for, it makes your question more understandable and usable for future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I am operating under the assumption that you have a `.class` file for `Person`, but no `.class` file for `Address`.  (Perhaps `Person` is a dependency from a different project?)*

The reason you cannot serialize `Person` (even though the `Address` field is transient) is that the serialization API uses the Java reflection API.  Although the JVM will load a class without loading all of its dependencies, the reflection API is not as forgiving.

The first time the reflection API is used to retrieve field information for a particular class, it retrieves and caches information for *all* fields in the class.  To do this, it has to resolve the types for every field in the class, and thus will attempt to load the class files for every field.  (You can see this in the Java source code: `ObjectOutputStream` uses [`ObjectStreamClass`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/ObjectStreamClass.java#ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID%28java.lang.Class%29), which calls [`Class.getDeclaredField`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java#Class.getDeclaredField%28java.lang.String%29), which calls a private method [`privateGetDeclaredFields`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Class.java#Class.privateGetDeclaredFields%28boolean%29), which resolves and caches all the field definitions for the class.)

**As a workaround**, if your code *never* actually uses any objects of type `Address`, you can simply create an empty `Address` class in the correct package, compile it, and add it to your class path:

```
public class Address { }
```

---

For those who think it isn't possible to use `Person` at runtime without an `Address` class definition, the following three classes demonstrate what the OP is talking about:

**Person.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Person implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private transient Address address;
    public Person(String name)  { this.name = name; }
    public Address getAddress() { return address; }
    public String getName()     { return name; }
}
```

**Address.java**

```
public class Address {
    private String address;
    public String getAddress()  { return address; }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOuputStream;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String...args) throws Exception {
        Person person = new Person("John Doe");
        System.out.println("Person successfully instantiated with name " + person.getName());

        // now attempt to serialize
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("person.out"));
        out.writeObject(person); // NoClassDefFoundError thrown here if Address.class doesn't exist
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Now compile `Test.java`, delete `Address.class`, and run `Test`:

```
$ javac Test.java
$ rm Address.class
$ java Test
Person successfully instantiated with name John Doe
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LAddress;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1897)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1624)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:69)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:442)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:430)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:327)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1130)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
        at Test.main(Test.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Address
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
        ... 12 more
```

Comment: Okay, thanks matts this answers my question completely. This answer should be the one voted on top because you specifically answered every aspect of my question, but I cannot vote it up because I don't have 15 reputation sorry...

Comment: Oh, I see that as owner of the question, I can vote it as accepted answer, which I did. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that to load an object, it must first load the class. To load the class, it must resolve the class of all the fields and if you don't have class `Address` you cannot load the class or example the field to determine that it is transient.

You can solve this by providing a dummy `Address` class which is at the end of your class path. i.e. is only used if not defined.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Peter, I will indeed just define a dummy class Address in the same package name as Address was defined in the Person project. I think I will then be able to serialize...

Answer (score 0):

For a class to be serialized, two conditions must be met:

- The class must implement the java.io.Serializable interface.
- All of the fields in the class must be serializable. If a field is not serializable, it must be marked transient.

You need to know Address class in order to build the project. That's unrelated to serialization of the object. Address class must be available at compile time...

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you

**Person.java**

```
    public class Person implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String sex;
        private String name;
        private transient Address address;

        public Person(String sex, String name) {
            this.sex = sex; this.name = name; 
        }
        public void setAddress(Address address) {
            this.address = address
        }

        private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) {
            try {
                os.defaultWriteObject();
                os.writeUTF(this.address.getAddress());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private void readObject(ObjectInputStream is) {
            try {
                is.defaultReadObject();
                this.address = new Address(is.readUTF());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

**Address.java**

```
    public class Address {
        private String address;
        public String getAddress()  { return address; }
        public void setAddress() { this address = address}
    }
```

**Test.java**

```
 public class Test {
    public static void main(String...args) throws Exception {
        Person person = new Person("John Doe");
        person.setAddress("test address");

        try {
            FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream("simple.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fis);
            os.writeObject(person);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("simple.txt");
            ObjectInputStream os = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            person = (Person) os.readObject();           

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```